# One of the underlined words is wrong. Choose either A, B, C or D

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, present-tense, progressive-aspect, present-progressive

"What (are:A) you talking (about:B)? (I'm:C) not (understand:D) you."

At first, I thought C, so the sentence would be "What are you talking about? I don't understand you." And I chose C because I believe "understand" is a state verb doesn't accept "ing".

But then some dudes said to me that D is definitely the correct choice, so the sentence would be "What are you talking about? I'm not understanding you."

So what do you say and why?